# mongodb how to delete_many based on mongo _ids

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection (`coll`) in  `db` looks like,

```
_id                                    pri_key
ObjectId("5b20f64dc227f879944f330c")   a_1
ObjectId("5b20f64dc227f879944f330d")   b_1
ObjectId("5b20f64dc227f879944f330e")   c_1
ObjectId("5b20f64dc227f879944f330f")   d_1
ObjectId("5b20f64dc227f879944f3310")   e_1
```

I want to `delete_many` docs using their `_id`s which are corresponding to a list (say `keys`) of `pri_key`, i.e.`keys = ['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']` in `coll`, I am wondering how to do that.

while I can do `db.coll.delete_many({'primary_key': {'$in': keys}})`, I suspect `MongoDB` handles `_id` faster than other keys defined in the docs.

UPDATE. the original problem is that I convert data stored in a `pandas` `DataFrame` (`df`) into a list of `dict`s, and then insert them into `mongo`. This `mongo` write is also an incremental insertion, meaning that if there are any overlapped docs between the collection in the db and the list, I will delete the docs in the collection first then insert the new ones using the list.

The deletion is using `pri_key`, so I get the `pri_key` values from the `df` into a list first, then simply using `db.coll.delete_many({'primary_key': {'$in': keys}})` to delete those overlapped docs in the collection.

The problem is that I found it very slowly especially when facing 10 million docs in a single collection. So I am wondering is there a way to speed up this process.

Comment: Since you already know how $in works, could you elaborate why you can't use `{_id: {$in: list_of_ids}}`?

Comment: @AlexBlex I like to know how to use `keys` to find `_id`s in `coll`, and then I can use these `_id`s in `delete_many`.

Comment: that means you will find `_id` with `$in` and then you will use that `_id` in delete many operation... Am I right?

Comment: What's the point? Searching for _ids by keys to delete documents by _ids  will always be slower than deleting documents by keys straight away.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet exactly correct

Comment: I m agree with @AlexBlex.... How the second process will be faster than the first one... In first one you are deleting them directly and in second you are doing find and delete operation... How this can be faster?

Comment: @AlexBlex okay, is there a way to speed up delete process, apart from dividing the whole batch into chunks and then delete them multiprocessingly.

Comment: I doubt deletion by chunks will be quicker. It seems you are falling to [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try to describe the original issue.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have updated my op, stating my original problem.

Comment: Could you confirm `pri_key` is actually a unique index?

Comment: @AlexBlex `pri_key` is usually a unique, but what if it is not unique sometimes

Comment: Okay, forget about uniqueness (although I find it quite misleading to name a non-unique field as 'primary_key'), do you have an index for this field in mongodb?

Comment: @AlexBlex it is defined as unique, it does not have any index for this field in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index in mongodb:

```
db.collection.createIndex({pri_key:1})
```

It will speed up deletion by `pri_key`.

If you will never ever have 2 documents with the same `pri_key`, it can be

```
db.collection.createIndex({pri_key:1}, {unique: true})
```

In this case an attempt to add a document with the same `pri_key` will result with an error.